# Рабы царя, царю

Tags: грамотная-речь

Они не рабы "царя" или "царю", как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Они не рабы царя - говорит о людях, которые: 1) не в его власти, свободные; 2) рабы другого хозяина. 
Они не рабы царю - говорит о людях, которые: 1) являются его друзьями, приятелями; 2) не являются царю никем.